# SwiftUI - How to get a transparent status bar when in a tabbed view?

Tags: swift, xcode, user-interface, swiftui

My app first root view is a tabbed view with two tabs. The second tab is a navigation view with a form. The setting can be summarised like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    TabView {
      // First view
      // ...

      NavigationView {
        Form {
          // Form details
          // ...
        }
      }
      .tabItem {
        // Text and image for the tab view item
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Problem is that the form view's background is not white, it is slightly contrasted (as for grouped lists) and this creates a disgraceful separation with the status bar at the top:

[image]

This behaviour is not present in other app such as Apple ones. For instance the main view of Pages app is a tab view and the status bar remains transparent and of the same colour as the top bar title.

[image]

I'd like the same behaviour as the iPhone settings app, with a header colour matching the status bar view.

The problem here seems to be the tab view that takes control of the status bar appearance, if I remove it all goes normal.

Is there a way to get this behaviour inside a tab view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your `TabView` in a `ZStack` and set `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)` for your stack

```swift
var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            TabView {
                Form {
                    Text("OK")
                }
            }.tabItem {
                Text("Show")
            }
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    }
```

Comment: This works, thanks! Btw applying `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)` modifier to the tab view directly works too, why using a ZStack?

Comment: Yes, it's work directly on tab view too, there is no reason to use ZStack at all

Comment: As of iOS 13.4, this seems to fling the navigation bar up almost past the status bar.  The only visible portion of the bar that I see is the size of the status bar, sitting untappable behind it. A rather odd way to break, but that's what happens...